Degree of an isogeny
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve,
The map $F: E \rightarrow E$ with $F(P) = mP$ where $P$ is a point on $E$ is an endomorphism of $E$ with degree $m^2$.
Why is the degree of endomorphism $F$ is $m$ square?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.
